# How can I solve the linear congruence for x with the use of an inverse?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider, for example, the linear congruence:

$56x \equiv 23 ($mod $93)$ if we know that the inverse of of $56$ modulo $93$ is $5$.

Multiplying both sides by the inverse, $5$, we have:
$280 x \equiv 115 ($mod $93)$.

Thus:
$x \equiv 115($mod $93)$.

From here on, I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Reduce 115  mod 93 (115-93=?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you already solved it. The solution is $x\equiv115\bmod 93$. Although it seems nicer to change $115$ for the equivalent $22$ to get $x\equiv 22\bmod 93$

Comment: This means that $x = 22 + k93$ for $k$ an integer, right?

Comment: Yes, the integers $x$ such that $56x$ leaves remainder $23$ when dividing by $93$ are those of the form $22+93k$